# Apache pig: checking how many lines with the same numbers (in any combinations) exist in a cvs input

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

ok guys,I'm a bit new here.
I want to run a pig script and check how many lines with the same numbers (in any combinations) exist in a cvs input

I do understand how to get the CVS into hadoop and how to parse it via pig.
I do understand how to iterate through the input lines and logic tells me that I need to sort each input line first and then do the count but I cannot figure out how to do it

See below my input CVS and what kind of output I expect to get.
Does anyone able to help here?

this is my input

123
321
213
456
564

and I want to get the following result

(3,{1,2,3})(2,{4,5,6})

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you some idea.

If the below one is your input

```
123 321 213 456 564
```

you can split the input into 5 values delimited by space then sore each value in ascending order like below.

```
123 123 123 456 456
```

Then you use word count program to find the output as you want.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me
How do you sort each line? 
I mean, how do you change the input line  "321" to 123 within the pig script?
this is what i'm not able to do

Comment: For that you can use UDF, You can write your own method in java to do this. You can start from [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html)

Comment: Ok, I was hoping to avoid UDF and do it straight via pig, anyway, thanks for your help.